# How to branch with TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I downloaded TortoiseHg 1.0 for evaluation.  For the life of me I can't figure out how to make a branch.  It seems to understand branches (e.g. in its repository browser) but I just can't seem to find a way to make a branch.  This seems like such a fundamental capability since out of the often touted benefits of DVC is the lightweight branching.

I Googled around and couldn't find much discussion of this topic (at least for recent versions) so I have to assume I'm missing something, right?

**Update:** So I flagged Chad Birch's answer below to answer the "new branch" issue.  As he correctly points out, you do a commit and then click on the branch button to bring up the branch maintenance dialog which is where you create new branches.  I kind of wish they had given us a context menu option for this.  Once you've branched, the next natural question is how to merge and this is also not obvious.  It turns out that option is buried in the repository explorer.  You need to select the head of another branch, right-click and then select "Merge with...".

Comment: Branching is seriously buried in a completely unintuitive aspect of workflow. Branching and committing are two very distinct operations and it makes no sense to bury branching deep within the commit UI. As I typically commit **before** branching, it did not occur to me to look under the commit UI. Branching is [still effectively undocumented even as of mid-2016](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commit.html?highlight=branch); Chad Birch points out what passes for branching documentation; it's still awful, but as he notes, he's only the messenger...

Answer (score 217, accepted):

[As shown in the docs](http://tortoisehg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commit.html), all you should need to do is just click on the <kbd>branch: default</kbd> button near the top of the commit dialog, and change to a new branch name.

Comment: With recent versions of Mercurial you need to do a `hg push --new-branch` to push a new branch to a remote repository.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365483/ for how to do this in TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 26):

To start new branch with TortoiseHg press Commit... then, above Commit message press Branch, then "Open new named branch: "

Answer (score 9):

Most of the time in mercurial, you `clone` the repository to make a branch.

You can then merge the separate repositories once you made your edits and commits.

This might sound like it would take up a lot of disk space but on most operating systems, mercurial will make hardlinks instead of copying the files. Anyway, disk space is normally cheap, and because it's local it's rather fast.

If you think about it, every "checkout" (in svn terminology) or "clone" (in mercurial terminology) is really a branch that will probably be merged back so it makes lots of sense that clones are the common way of making branches.

Comment: It's not convenient for feature branches.

Comment: Agreed. If you have long-running (semi-permanent) branches, such as a version-1-stable branch and a version-2-stable branch, you'll want to use [named branches](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NamedBranches). See also the [mercurial branch documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Branch).

Comment: -1.  This is at best a hack.  Cloning for branching doesn't work at all if you're following a remote repository, since you can't push your local changes.  This means you can't share your branch with other developers you're working with.  The correct way to branch is to create a named branch within your repository.

Comment: Cloning is still how the official mercurial book recommends 'big picture' branches http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html#id385287     Don't shoot the messenger.

Answer (score 9):

Just wanted to add that in order to push new branch to remote repository there is a checkbox on the Synchronize tab under Options of "Allow push of a new branch" - you have to remember to turn it off again right afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Before commiting, click on Branch button (see image), Then select a branch or create a new one (by typing where you select the branches).

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9bMH.png)