# How to work with a different branch in TortoiseHG?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am working with TortoiseHG on a Windows 7 system.

I was working on the default branch, and the R&D team wanted to try out a different algorithm, so I created a new branch using the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2562957/895), called `quadraticTest`.

A couple of commits were made to this branch, and the output was found unsuitable.

Now I want to go back and work on the default branch without merging changes from the `quadraticTest` branch.

Basically, I'm searching for the GUI equivalent of `hg update default` command

How do I move the Working directory back to the default branch with ToritoiseHG?

Comment: @user2864740: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Okay, so you have changes in the current WC (in "quadraticTest") and now want to get back to "default" discarding all changes in the current WC (and wanting to never work on "quadraticTest" again)?

Comment: I want to now work on default, but keep the changes in the repository for the future. Basically, I'm searching for the GUI equivalent of `hg update default` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking at the tree, with the graph view, find the revision you want to check out, right-click on it, and select `Update...`

But let's say that you're having trouble finding the commit -- maybe you have a lot of branches, and so you don't see the revision you want to check out. Turn on the Filter Toolbar (View > Filter Toolbar).

Look on the right. You'll see a dropdown that says something like `★ Show all ★`. Click on that to list all your open branches. Select the branch you want to check out, and it will filter the graph view so only commits on that branch show up. Then it'll be easy to find the most recent commit on the `default` branch, because it'll be the top one.